# Run flutter application into iOS virtual device on virtualized OSX

Tags: flutter, virtual-machine, ios-simulator, flutter-test

I have some performance problems running my Flutter application inside iOS simulator installed inside a VirtualBox OSx machine. The simulator run and the application is deployed without any problem. But there is lag when the screen has to be redrawn. For example, when I click on a button which opens a modal sheet, the image is stuck, I can unlock it simply dragging the IOs bottom bar of a few pixels. It's difficult to test the application since every time I have to move that bar a few pixels in order to update the phone image. This is an example of my problem:

[image]

As you can see the image is redrawn just after I click and move the iOS bottom bar. 
Here a simulation of a native iOS app:

[image]

Here as you can see the screen has to redraw, I don't need to move the bottom bar. 
Any suggestion?